# Unable to click on tile using Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am new user of Protractor. Need help as i am unable to click on Some Name, having below HTML

```
<div class="department-click" 
<div class="department-click" onclick="GLOBAL_SERVICE_ID=405;changeLocation('#/aaaa');_routeFrom='home'">
   <!-- <div class="department-click" onclick="changeLocation('#/aaaa')"> -->
   <div class="department-icon custom-svgbg1 layout-column layout-align-center-center">
      <!--                  <svg style="height:80px; width:80px;" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> -->
      <!--                         <path fill="#fff" d="M12,3L1,9L12,15L21,10.09V17H23V9M5,13.18V17.18L12,21L19,17.18V13.18L12,17L5,13.18Z" /> -->
      <!--                     </svg> -->
      <svg height="80px" viewBox="0 0 92.168 92.168" width="80px">
         <rect clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" height="92.168" width="92.168" x="0"></rect>
         <path d="M4.994,53.166V37.65l-3.248-1.418c-1.185-0.511-1.077-2.165,0.2-2.565l44.208-13.824  c0.255-0.091,0.566-0.091,0.821,0l44.244,13.915c1.26,0.4,1.26,2.182,0.019,2.6L47.123,55.385c-0.366,0.145-0.73,0.145-1.096-0.019  L7.731,38.832v14.352c1.022,0.219,1.86,0.673,2.554,1.309c2.499,2.257,2.573,6.312,1.807,9.351  c-0.766,2.947-2.482,5.802-5.018,7.403c-0.475,0.309-1.022,0.273-1.477-0.019c-2.592-1.618-4.361-4.456-5.146-7.366  c-0.802-3.036-0.711-7.021,1.752-9.293C2.968,53.875,3.899,53.384,4.994,53.166L4.994,53.166z M6.782,35.468  c0.091,0.017,0.183,0.053,0.255,0.091l39.556,17.096l40.322-17.388L46.557,22.57L6.18,35.195L6.782,35.468z M69.508,51.201  c0-0.745,0.602-1.365,1.368-1.365c0.749,0,1.368,0.619,1.368,1.365v10.532c0,5.22-6.951,8.531-15.781,9.894  c-6.495,1.001-13.74,1.037-20.233,0.019c-8.558-1.328-15.181-4.567-15.181-9.896V51.457c0-0.764,0.619-1.365,1.368-1.365  c0.747,0,1.368,0.6,1.368,1.365v10.294c0,3.675,5.619,6.076,12.863,7.204c6.221,0.982,13.172,0.945,19.395-0.019  c7.534-1.165,13.464-3.619,13.464-7.203V51.201z M3.096,63.17c0.547,2.018,1.643,3.983,3.248,5.257  c1.515-1.273,2.573-3.219,3.103-5.257c0.511-1.965,0.675-5.167-0.985-6.676c-1.151-1.018-3.286-0.945-4.397,0.072  C2.402,58.095,2.568,61.186,3.096,63.17L3.096,63.17z" fill="#3A3E49 "></path>
      </svg>
   </div>
   <h3 class="clamp2">
      <span>
      Some Name
      </span>
   </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the attempts you have already made

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the element by css:

```
element(by.css('.department-click .clamp2 span'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which element you want to click, next line is locating the element by css and then clicking it:

```
element(by.css('h3.clamp2 span')).click();
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with some explanation